# I need two types of easily crackable asymmetric and symmetric encryption

Tags: public-key, symmetric

I have a school project in which I'm comparing asymmetric and symmetric encryption. I need two different types of *easily crackable* encryption, one symmetric and one asymmetric. I am planning on encrypting a string of text and then cracking that encryption.

I would like the encryption (and cracking if possible) to be done in Python, but if that isn't possible it's fine. I would also prefer it to take under 24 hours to crack. I have a server with an NVIDIA Tesla M60 GPU and an Intel Xeon E5-2690 at 2.60Ghz.

Thanks!

Comment: Plain old DES might be worth looking into here (either with or without linear cryptanalysis techniques). As for asymmetric pick anything you like / can somewhat explain and pick a small-enough key-size, e.g. RSA with two 256-bit primes (which Cado-NFS / msieve / GGNFS should be able to break using the GNFS).

Comment: When you say "in python" do you mean pure Python, or Python with the Numpy library? Because Numpy is a python wrapper around some C, and therefore MUCH faster. Like, >10x the speed, sometimes >50x.

Comment: For the symmetric system, would something like AES with a restricted key space (such as the first 80 key bits always 0) be acceptable?

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to prove by cracking the encryption systems. That's not entirely clear to me - or not at all, really.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica For one part of my project, I have to record the time it takes to crack asymmetric and symmetric encryption. Not really proving anything, this is more for data.

Comment: @EugeneStyer How would I be able to crack that?

Comment: If we take AES-128, and require the first 80 bits be 0, then we have only 48 bits of key unknown, which would be doable by brute force.  You could adjust the number of fixed 0 bits in the key to adjust the time required.

Comment: Reverse mining, where it gets easier to get the key each time a zero is added :P